# Unlimited allocation of memory TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0

I have custom property that stores objects of class Menu:

```
private menu: Menu[] = [];
```

Where `class Menu`:

```
export class Menu {
  constructor(public url: string, public title: string, public submenu: Menu[], public role: string, public avaliable: boolean) {
  }
}
```

In class service `MenuService` I fill up `this.menu`:

```
 this.menu = [
      new Menu('/dashboard/p', 'menu_zavuc_1', null, 'Principal', true),
      new Menu('/school/%school_id%/h/management', 'menu_zavuc_2', null, 'Principal', true),
      new Menu('/school/%school_id%/h/planning', 'menu_zavuc_3', null, 'Principal', true)];
```

There is another method in the same class `MenuService`:

```
public getMenuItems(profile: MenuHeader): IMenuItem[] {

    let arr: IMenuItem[] = [];
    this.menu.filter(function (element: Menu) {
      return element.role == profile.role();
    });

    let arrOut: IMenuItem[] = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

       let url = arr[i].url.replace('%school_id%', profile.organizationId().toString());
      url = url.replace('%pupil_id%', profile.getId().toString());

      arrOut.push({
        url: arr[i].url,
        title: arr[i].title,
        role: arr[i].role
      });
    }
    return arrOut;
  }
```

Method `getMenuItems` is called from template:

```
<div *ngFor="let menu of menuService.getMenuHeaders()">
   <div *ngFor="let item of menuService.getMenuItems(menu)"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see it is loop in loop.

Problem is when I call method `getMenuItems()` it invokes unlimited memory allocation.

I think cause is in `this.menu.filter()` when I try reuse the same object `this.menu` for some operations. Possible each time `this.menu` is linked to previous values.

Maybe to clone `this.menu`?

If comment body of `getmenuItems()` and write only: `console.log(profile.role());` it works fine

If rewrite function on:

```
public getMenuItems(profile: MenuHeader): IMenuItem[] {
    let list: IMenuItem[] = [];


    let l = {
      url: '',
      title: 'sss',
      role: 'sdadad'
    };

    let a = {
      url: '',
      title: 'sss',
      role: 'sdadad'
    };

    list.push(l);
    list.push(a);

    return list;
}
```

It works fine!

Comment: I don't see the use of `this.menu.filter`. Can you please point out where you are using it's value?

Comment: arr is always empty and gets returned (instead of arrOut)

Comment: Sorry it should be  `return arrOut`; it is correct in code

Comment: If comment body of `getmenuItems()` and write only: `console.log(profile.role());` it works fine

Comment: as some already pointed out, arr stays empty and your filter does nothing useful. can you post the code of menuItem and menuHeader?

Comment: I solved this problem, who is interested I can post answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this will fix your memory problem, but it seems to me that there are a few mistakes in the code.

Be aware that `.filter` on an array does not change the array, it only RETURNS a filtered array.

```
this.menu.filter(function (element: Menu) {
      return element.role == profile.role();
    });
```

Also you are looping over `arr` but that variable stays initialized with [].

So, did you mean the following?

```
let arr: IMenuItem[] = this.menu.filter(function (element: Menu) {
      return element.role == profile.role();
    });
```

Also do you really want to return `arr` ?
It seems that you really wanted to return `arrOut`

That could be written as:

```
public getMenuItems(profile: MenuHeader): IMenuItem[] {
    return this.menu
      .filter( (element: Menu) => element.role == profile.role() )
      .map( (element: Menu):MenuItem => {
          return { 
              url: element.url,
              title: element.title,
              role: element.role
          }
      });
}
```

In this way, all your operations on "this.menu" are pure local in your method.

Perhaps that helps to tackle your memory problem

warm regards

Comment: I made these recommendations, problem is not solved, the same behaviour

Comment: If comment body of `getmenuItems()` and write only: `console.log(profile.role());` it works fine

Comment: Look at  my updating